# How to separate times of day into 3 buckets: morning, afternoon, and evening?

Tags: php, arrays, time, grouping, bucket

I'm looking to count values from an array that contain a certain number. Basically, I'm looking to plot a graph os visits, and want to do it as 'morning', 'afternoon' and 'evening'. So I want to count times, such as `17:38` as `17`, then count them so I can classify if visits were morning, afternoon or evening.

```
$time_array = array("17:45","13:12","09:29","17:32","16:49","14:18");

$counts = array_count_values($time_array);
$morning_counts = $counts['09'] + $counts['10'] + $counts['11'];
$afternoon_counts = $counts['12'] + $counts['13'] + $counts['14'] + $counts['15'] + $counts['16'];
$evening_counts = $counts['17'] + $counts['18'] + $counts['19'] + $counts['20'] + $counts['21'] + $counts['22'] + $counts['23'];
```

Expected output from sample data:

```
$morning_counts = 1
$afternoon_count = 3
$evening_counts = 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by creating counter variables. We can then create ranges of time frames using `range()`. Then get the values before the `:` in the time string as the hour and then compare that against the range, if it's in the range, add 1 to the counter.

```
<?php
    $time_array = array("17:45","13:12","09:29","17:32","16:49","14:18");

    # create counter vars
    $mornCount = 0;
    $afternoonCount = 0;
    $eveCount = 0;

    # create range of times to compare against
    $mornRange = range(0, 11);
    $afternoonRange = range(12, 16);
    $eveRange = range(17, 23);

    foreach ($time_array as $time)
    {
        $compareTimeArr = explode(':', $time); # get first two chars of time
        $compareTime = $compareTimeArr[0];

        if (in_array($compareTime, $mornRange)) {
            $mornCount++;
        } elseif (in_array($compareTime, $afternoonRange)) {
            $afternoonCount++;
        } elseif (in_array($compareTime, $eveRange)) {
            $eveCount++;
        }
    }

    echo '<pre>'. print_r($mornCount,1) .'</pre>';
    echo '<pre>'. print_r($afternoonCount,1) .'</pre>';
    echo '<pre>'. print_r($eveCount,1) .'</pre>';
```

refs:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Answer (score 1):

Simplest option:

```
$time_array = array("17:45","13:12","09:29","17:32","16:49","14:18");
$times = [];
foreach ($time_array as $time) {
    $times[] = substr($time, 0, 2);
}

// Proceed with original code, but swap $time_array for $times
```

I think it's pretty ugly though. I'd usually recommend to work with DateTimes or DatePeriods instead of strings.

Comment: Okay, well I'm getting this from a database, so maybe just COUNT where date BETWEEN function and do it three times?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to work for me, it returns an aggregate number of times much higher than those that exist?

Answer (score 1):

Being REALLY simplistic about it you could do this in a switch statement

```
<?php
$time_array = array("17:45","13:12","09:29","17:32","16:49","14:18");

$morn = 0;
$after = 0;
$eve = 0;
$other = 0;
foreach ($time_array as $time) {
    $t = explode(':',$time)[0];
    switch ($t) {
        case '09':
        case '10':
        case '11':
        case '12':
            $morn++;
            break;

        case '13':
        case '14':
        case '15':
        case '16':
            $after++;
            break;

        case '17':
        case '18':
        case '19':
        case '20':
        case '21':
        case '22':
        case '23':
            $eve++;
            break;
        default:
            $other++;
    }
}
echo "Morning = $morn<br>";
echo "Afternoon = $after<br>";
echo "Evening= $eve<br>";
echo "Other = $other<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it in just a few lines:

```
$counts = array_reduce($time_array, function($counts, $time) {
  $hour = (int)substr($time, 0, 2);
  $moment = in_array($hour, range(9, 12)) ? 'morning' : (in_array($hour, range(13, 16)) ? 'afternoon' : 'evening');
  $counts[$moment]++;
  return $counts;
}, ['morning' => 0, 'afternoon' => 0, 'evening' => 0]);
```

[Demo here](https://3v4l.org/D7c9f)

Comment: This doesn't reference the $time_array variable anywhere?

Comment: @Nathan `$time_array` is the array being passed into the function  -- I don't expect to see it reappear in this snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes another solution

```
<?php
$time_array = array("17:45","13:12","09:29","17:32","16:49","14:18");
$counts = countValues($time_array);
$morning_counts = $counts['09'] + $counts['10'] + $counts['11'] + $counts['12'];
$afternoon_counts = $counts['12'] + $counts['13'] + $counts['14'] + $counts['15'] + $counts['16'];
$evening_counts = $counts['17'] + $counts['18'] + $counts['19'] + $counts['20'] + $counts['21'] + $counts['22'] + $counts['23'] + $counts['24'];

var_dump($morning_counts, $afternoon_counts, $evening_counts);

function countValues($time_array) {
    $result = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 23; $i++) {
        $key = ($i < 10) ? ('0' . $i) : (string) $i;
        $result[$key] = 0;
    }
    foreach ($time_array as $time) {
        $key = strstr($time, ':', true);
        $result[$key]++;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `preg_match` you can get also the count of times.

```
$time_array = array("17:45","13:12","09:29","17:32","16:49","14:18");
function time_results($time_array){
    $result = array('morning_counts'=>0,'afternoon_counts'=>0,'evening_counts'=>0,'total'=>0);
    $result['total'] = count($time_array);
    foreach($time_array as $time){
        if(preg_match('/^(09|10|11|12)\:*/',$time)){
            $result['morning_counts'] += 1;
        }else if(preg_match('/^(13|14|15|16)\:*/',$time)){
            $result['afternoon_counts'] += 1;
        }else if(preg_match('/^(17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24)\:*/',$time)){
            $result['evening_counts'] += 1;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

var_dump(time_results($time_array));
/*
result : array(4) { ["morning_counts"]=> int(1) ["afternoon_counts"]=> int(3) ["evening_counts"]=> int(2) ["total"]=> int(6) } 
*/
```

Comment: I fear for the person who copy-pastes these regex patterns.  **1.** You don't need a capture group **2.** Characters classes will reduce the number of piped conditions that need to be used **3.** You don't need to escape `:` **4.** `:*` doesn't make any logical sense for the sample data.  Furthermore, regex is avoidable here and will likely prove this answer to be the least efficient on the page.

Answer (score 0):

### This is the first time I've ever used the "spaceship operator" aka "3-way-comparison operator" on a snippet that wasn't calling `usort()`.

It is perfectly suited for this task because you want to generate three buckets for your time values.

The spaceship operator returns one of three different values: `-1`, `0`, and `1`.  It's job is to compare two strings and decide if the value on the left is `less than`, `equal to`, or `greater than` the right side value -- it then returns the respective numeric value mentioned in my previous sentence.

To set up this unique comparison operator (available from php7+), we need to boil down the input numbers so that they can be correctly "bucketed".

Most people rush to `explode()` (and too often don't use the 3rd parameter (limit) to inform php that no more than 2 elements are desired).  I do not, because I don't like to generate an array from a string just to capture a substring.  Because the time values are predictably formatted, the best tool for the task will be `substr($time, 0, 2)`, but closely followed by `strstr($time, ':', true)` and if you want to be tricky `"$time[0]$time[1]"`.

I hope my inline comments will clear up any other confusions about my concise and powerful snippet.  (Just 4 lines of working code!)

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Jgp4Z))

```
$time_array = ["17:45", "13:12", "09:29", "17:32", "16:49", "14:18"];

$buckets = array_fill_keys([-1, 0, 1], 0);  // initialize buckets with 0 values

foreach ($time_array as $time) {
    ++$buckets[(int)sqrt(substr($time, 0, 2) - 8) <=> 2];
    //                                            ^^^^^-- 3-way comparison versus 2 
    //                                       ^^^--------- subtract 8 from the two-digit number
    //                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------------- extract first two digits from time string
    //             ^^^^^^-------------------------------- get squareroot value
    //         ^^^^--------------------------------- convert to integer (truncate decimals)
}

echo "Morning Count: {$buckets[-1]}\n";   // Hours: 00:00 to 11:59 ->12hrs (calculates as: 0, 1)
echo "Afternoon Count: {$buckets[0]}\n";  // Hours: 12:00 to 16:59 -> 5hrs (calculates as: 2)
echo "Evening Count: {$buckets[1]}";      // Hours: 17:00 to 23:59 -> 7hrs (calculates as: 3, 4)
```

Output:

```
Morning Count: 1
Afternoon Count: 3
Evening Count: 2
```

---

How does the calculation process breakdown?

```
foreach (range(0, 23) as $t) {
    $calc = (float)sqrt($t - 8);
    echo "$t: " , (int)$calc , " ... [float value from sqrt was: $calc]\n";
}
```

Breakdown from time values `0` to `23`:

```
//  |--------------------------------------------input time value
//  v  v-----------------------------------------final calculated value
//                                       vvv-----before converted to integer value
    0: 0 ... [float value from sqrt was: NAN]
    1: 0 ... [float value from sqrt was: NAN]
    2: 0 ... [float value from sqrt was: NAN]
    3: 0 ... [float value from sqrt was: NAN]
    4: 0 ... [float value from sqrt was: NAN]
    5: 0 ... [float value from sqrt was: NAN]
    6: 0 ... [float value from sqrt was: NAN]
    7: 0 ... [float value from sqrt was: NAN]
    8: 0 ... [float value from sqrt was: 0]
    9: 1 ... [float value from sqrt was: 1]
    10: 1 ... [float value from sqrt was: 1.4142135623731]
    11: 1 ... [float value from sqrt was: 1.7320508075689]
    12: 2 ... [float value from sqrt was: 2]
    13: 2 ... [float value from sqrt was: 2.2360679774998]
    14: 2 ... [float value from sqrt was: 2.4494897427832]
    15: 2 ... [float value from sqrt was: 2.6457513110646]
    16: 2 ... [float value from sqrt was: 2.8284271247462]
    17: 3 ... [float value from sqrt was: 3]
    18: 3 ... [float value from sqrt was: 3.1622776601684]
    19: 3 ... [float value from sqrt was: 3.3166247903554]
    20: 3 ... [float value from sqrt was: 3.4641016151378]
    21: 3 ... [float value from sqrt was: 3.605551275464]
    22: 3 ... [float value from sqrt was: 3.7416573867739]
    23: 3 ... [float value from sqrt was: 3.8729833462074]
```